# Delegate is nil when custom class is created for NSTableview?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I have created a custom class for NSTableview and then created a Protocol/delegate for row selection in the custom class.Then in the View controller XIB i got NSTableview and I have changed the class to Custom class. I created a IBOutlet for the same and then set the custom delegate to **self** inside the method **initWithNibName** from view controller. And also I have written the delegate methods inside the View controller. But the delegate method is not called on the row selection. The delegate object is nil and also delegate is not reposing to the selector. Could any one guide me what am i doing wrong or if any thing is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to move the setDelegate call to **NSViewController**'s **viewDidLoad**

Comment: In xcode 5 and mac 10.9 there is not viewdidload functions available. Is there any other solution.

Comment: You can connect the delegate at the XIB itself. You can override loadView method and move setDelegate call also fine.

Comment: But the problem is if we are over riding loadView all the subviews in the XIB get removed right?

Comment: No. it don't remove the subview. -(void)loadView{[super loadView];[yourView setDelegate:Self];}